# Excel Transpose - Based on Cell Values

Tags: excel, transpose

I have been trying to find out a way to transpose only certain columns into rows in excel in order to achieve my result.

Since I need the output to be text values, I have been unable to use pivot table for my purpose. Here is the attached image which shows what I have and what I need.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: This would not be a transpose as your elements are resorted in your results table. Is this a one off process or a regularly completed task? You could use `MATCH` and `INDEX` to extract the timestamps that match your hearders.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) technical tag but I have found that these are the best solution providing that you allow certain parameters to be dynamic; e.g. assigned according to the size and nature of the raw data.

```
Sub collate()
    Dim rw As Long, rc As Long, rr As Long, r As Long, c As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet2")    '<-set this worksheet reference properly!
        rr = Application.Match("item id", .Columns(1), 0)
        rc = .Cells(rr, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 2
        .Cells(rr, rc + 1) = .Cells(rr + 1, 2).Value2

        For rw = rr + 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, .Columns(rc), 0)) Then
                .Cells(Rows.Count, rc).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = .Cells(rw, 1).Value2
            End If
            If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2, .Cells(rr, rc).Resize(1, 999), 0)) Then
                .Cells(rr, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1) = .Cells(rw, 2).Value2
            End If

            r = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 1).Value2, .Columns(rc), 0)
            c = Application.Match(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2, .Rows(rr), 0)
            .Cells(r, c) = .Cells(rw, 3).Value
        Next rw

        With .Cells(rr, rc).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                 .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
            End With
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(0, 1)
                 .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Rows(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, Header:=xlNo
            End With
        End With

    End With
End Sub
```

After running this on an approximate duplication of your data I came up with these results.

[image: Collate and Sort]

Note that I have specifically altered the data with an out-of-order 3005 entry in order to demonstrate the horizontal sorting routine performed on the resulting data.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following solution as per your example.

```
G3=IF(SUMIFS($C$4:$C$13,$A$4:$A$13,$F4,$B$4:$B$13,G$3)>0,SUMIFS($C$4:$C$13,$A$4:$A$13,$F4,$B$4:$B$13,G$3),"")
```

This assumes that each combination of "Item ID" and "Scan Event ID" only shows up once. This allows us to use the `SUMIFS` function adding up the only relevant result. Note that excel adds it based on that dates serial number.

The if is to prevent Excel from displaying formulas returning a 0 and being parsed as an actual date.

You would then drag the formula to the rest of your output table. Regards,